# Получение переменных из разных блоков кода C#

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Могу ли я каким-то образом достучаться из одного блока кода до другого блока кода и получить от туда значение переменной (а может даже и саму переменную)? Я попытался с помощью рефлексии, но дальше не смог, не могу понять, как получить значения этих переменных

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var type = typeof(Program);

        var method = type.GetMethod("M");
        var body = method.GetMethodBody();
        var variables = body.LocalVariables; //что дальше?
    }

    public void M()
    {
        int a = 5;
        string b = "asdf";
    }
}
```

Comment: Переменной не существует за пределами блока, она существует во время выполнения блока и существовать она может не только как где-то в памяти, так и в виде значения в каком-то из регистров процессора, а может и вообще не существовать никак, если компилятор смог как-то заоптимизировать код. Так что ответ на ваш вопрос — нет.

Comment: Через рефлексию можно обращаться только к *членам классов*

Comment: @АндрейNOP понятно, не знал про то, что хранится может и в регистре процессора

Comment: используй референсы (`ref`) или `out` в параметрах метода. Возможно это поможет тебе. Не совсем то что ты хочешь, но авось)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берем ваш метод

```cs
public void M()
{
    int a = 5;
    string b = "asdf";
}
```

Компилируем, получаем ассемблер

```
Program.M()
    L0000: ret
```

Компилятор просто взял и выкинул эти переменные из кода за ненадобностью, и правильно сделал. Приехали, на этом расследование завершено.

---

Окей, ради справедливости, давайте посмотрим на неоптимизированный Debug код.

```
Program.M()
    L0000: push rbp
    L0001: sub rsp, 0x30
    L0005: lea rbp, [rsp+0x30]
    L000a: xor eax, eax
    L000c: mov [rbp-4], eax         ; int a = 0;
    L000f: mov [rbp-0x10], rax      ; string b = null;
    L0013: mov [rbp+0x10], rcx
    L0017: cmp dword ptr [0x7ffcbd09c2f0], 0 ; стек переполнен?
    L001e: je short L0025                    ; если да
    L0020: call 0x00007ffd109ec500           ; throw new StackOverflowException();
    L0025: nop
    L0026: mov dword ptr [rbp-4], 5 ; a = 5;
    L002d: mov rax, 0x20db06e28c8   ; константа, адрес адреса "asdf"
    L0037: mov rax, [rax]           ; получить адрес "asdf"
    L003a: mov [rbp-0x10], rax      ; b = "asdf";
    L003e: nop
    L003f: add rsp, 0x30
    L0043: pop rbp
    L0044: ret
```

То есть если собирать Debug сборку, то значения переменных можно будет получить. Точнее есть такая теоретическая возможность.

Само собой константы типа `0x20db06e28c8` определяются во время JIT компиляции, как итог достать значение в рантайме можно, но очень нелегко. Еще следует учитывать, что JIT часть методов вообще не компилирует до тех пор, пока они не понадобятся. Например, зачем ему компилировать весь .NET в память, если вы 99% методов из него не используете? Логично же, что не стоит этого делать.

Что касается имен переменных, их нет даже в IL коде, то есть они существуют только в C# и при сборке удаляются.